# Getting eregi deprecated error message

Tags: php

How can I replace the eregi on this code with pregmatch?

```
$subemail=$_POST['emailadd'];

$regex = "^[_+a-z0-9-]+(\.[_+a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]{1,})*\.([a-z]{2,}){1}$";

if(!eregi($regex, $subemail)){
//do this
}
```

Comment: Looks like a compatible expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below code.

```
$regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/'; 

if (preg_match($regex, $email)) {
 echo $email . \" is a valid email. We can accept it.\";
} else { 
 echo $email . \" is an invalid email. Please try again.\";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to validate email?

```
var_dump(filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
```

Comment: thanks. will return true but my complete algorithm needs more than just getting true or false. anyway, big thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add delimiters(I use `/`) before and after your original regex and then add `i` flags at the end.

```
if(!eregi( "/". $regex ."/i", $subemail)){
  //do this
}
```